# Array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Trying to create an array of structs (new to C), but I am getting a "array type has incomplete element type" when I try to initialize the array.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
typedef struct morsechar
{
   char  character;
   char* morse;
} MorseChar;

struct MorseChar lookup[] ={{'A', ".-"},    {'B', "-..."},  {'C', "-.-."},  
                            {'D', "-.."},   {'E', "."},     {'F', "..-."},      
                            {'G', "--."},   {'H', "...."},  {'I', ".."},
                            {'J', ".---"},  {'K', "-.-"},   {'L', ".-.."},
                            {'M', "--"},    {'N', "-."},    {'O', "---"},
                            {'P', ".--."},  {'Q', "--.-"},  {'R', ".-."},
                            {'S', "..."},   {'T', "-"},     {'U', "..-"},
                            {'V', "...-"},  {'W', ".--"},   {'X', "-..-"},
                            {'Y', "-.--"},  {'Z', "--.."},  {'0', "-----"}, 
                            {'1', ".----"}, {'2', "..---"}, {'3', "...--"},
                            {'4', "....-"}, {'5', "....."}, {'6', "-...."},    
                            {'7', "--..."}, {'8', "---.."}, {'9', "----."},
                            {'.', "#"},     {'-', "^"}};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have defined types `struct morsechar` and `MorseChar`, but you are trying to use the undefined type `struct MorseChar`.  Instead, write

```
MorseChar lookup[] = { /* Same as before */ };
```

Comment: or `struct morsechar` but then the typedef would be superfluous. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but with that correction I am still getting the same error: array type has incomplete element type

Comment: @Cory Also it's not necessary to specify a struct tag when using a typedef unless it's a recursive structure: `typedef struct { ... } MorseChar;` is sufficient.